# fread with yaml = TRUE read Type Date as character

Tags: r, date, data.table, yaml, fwrite

I am trying to save and read a data.table using fread with yaml = TRUE. This should preserve the
column types.

When I read the file using fread("filename", yaml = TRUE), numbers, factors and characters have the correct type, but the type "Date" is converted to "character".

Here is an example:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(date = as.POSIXct(c("2006-05-01", "2006-05-02")), 
                 b = as.factor(c(1,2)), 
                 c = c(3,4))

print(class(dt$date))

fwrite(dt, "dt.csv", yaml = TRUE)


dt <- fread("dt.csv", yaml = TRUE)

print(class(dt$date))
```

here is the csv file

[csv file with yaml header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH1SP.png)

Is it possible to preserve the "Date" type when reading the file ?

Comment: Share the csv file directly as text not as an image.

Comment: Sorry about that, the file is not needed to run the code.

Comment: This is indeed an unexpected behavior. I followed with an open issue [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1656)

Comment: The issue was finally filed [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3999)